# Is there a direct object in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The sun shone brightly all day long.

Is "all" the direct object here? It seems (to me) that it may be. Or is "all day long" a unit with adverbial implications tied to the verb "shone." If "all" is indeed the direct object (and not attached to "day long") then what becomes of "day long"? Does it then modify the sun as in "The day long sun"?
Thank you very much.

Comment: To have a direct object, a sentence must have a transitive verb. That sentence contains only one verb ("shone", past tense of "to shine"), and it is not transitive. (Note that the verb "to shine" has other definitions in which is *is* transitive.)

Comment: No: there's no transitive verb present. "Brightly" and "all day long" are both modifiers in clause structure.

Comment: No, It’s like *The sun rose early.* No transitive verb, no object.

Answer (score 1):

No, there can't be an object of the verb "to shine" because it is intransitive. In "to shine shoes" the meaning is such that "shoes" is an object.
"All day long" is an adverbial.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/long_2)) **long** ​ adverb
> used after a noun to emphasize that something happens for the whole of a particular period of time
>
> - We had to wait all day long.
> - The baby was crying all night long.
> - They stayed up the whole night long.

> (**CoGEL § 8.52**)   **Realization [of adjuncts of time]**
> No other type of adjunct has such a wide range of grammatical realizations
> available as has the adjunct of time. Especially notable is the use of noun
> phrases and prepositional phrases. The noun phrase occurs for position,
> duration, and frequency

The duration is based on the day; it is clear that "long" is not needed to communicate the same idea; it is nothing more than an emphasizer. The following sentence says the same thing, and "all day" is the adverbial phrase.

- The sun shone brightly all day.

"All" is the determiner; one is needed whether you use "long" or not, but not all are idiomatic; the use of *certain determiners* becomes possible when a preposition is added.

- The sun shone brightly every day.
- The sun shone brightly each day.
- The sun shone brightly the first day.
- <s>The sun shone brightly the day.</s>
  (*instead*) The sun shone brightly that day.
- <s>The sun shone brightly a day.</s>
  (*instead*)  The sun shone brightly for a day.

For instance if "several" is used as a determiner, the use of the preposition "for" is preferred (possibly this is the only really idiomatic choice).

- The sun shone brightly for several days.

Answer (score 0):

"All day long" is an adverb phrase, in which the adverb "long" is modified by the noun phrase "all day." More specifically, "all day" is a measure phrase; compare this to examples like "three hours late" ([Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) , p. 574). Such noun phrases can also modify verbs directly, as in sentences like "We argued about it all weekend" (*ibid.,* p. 707).